# Java: tips to add classpath

Tags: java

I have both a library.jar and program.jar in Java folder.

What is the correct command line to run? One method I tried is:

```
C:>java -cp c:\java\library.jar;.\java\program.jar program [param]
```

Comment: Argh, forgot to add the missing "program"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
java -cp c:\java\library.jar;.\java\program.jar package.the.MainClass [param]
```

From http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/classpath.html

> **Folders and archive files**
>
> When classes are stored in a directory
>   (folder), like
>
> ```
> c:\java\MyClasses\utility\myapp, then
> ```
>
> the class path entry points to the
>   directory that contains the first
>   element of the package name. (in this
>   case,C:\java\MyClasses, since the
>   package name is utility.myapp.)
>
> But when classes are stored in an
>   archive file (a .zip or .jar file) the
>   class path entry is the path to and
>   including the .zip or .jar file. For
>   example, to use a class library that
>   is in a .jar file, the command would
>   look something like this:
>
> ```
> C:> java -classpath C:\java\MyClasses\myclasses.jar utility.myapp.Cool
> ```
>
> **Multiple specifications**
>
> To find class files in the directory
>   C:\java\MyClasses as well as classes
>   in C:\java\OtherClasses, you would set
>   the class path to:
>
> ```
> C:> java -classpath C:\java\MyClasses;C:\java\OtherClasses ...
> ```
>
> Note that the two paths are separated
>   by a semicolon.

Comment: Can I just specify with MainClass instead of package.the.MainClass?

Comment: Not if it's inside a package. You've got to `cd` to the package root and add `.` to the classpath.

Comment: I see, my was on the root of the Jar

Answer (score 0):

If you intend for your program.jar to be an executable JAR, you'll have to run it this way (and read [this](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/introcs/85application/jar/jar.html)):

```
java -jar program.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Classpath entries can also contain the wildcard(*) character. For example, the class path entry `C:\java\*` specifies all JAR files in the `C:\java` directory and will be expanded into `C:\java\library.jar;C:\java\program.jar`.